# how to change background or textLabel color in IASKSpecifierValuesViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, settings, inappsettingskit

i' m using InAppSettingsKit on my project. 
i customized IASKAppSettingsViewController But i don't customize IASKSpecifierValuesViewController.

my IASKAppSettingsViewController Custom Class;

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: IASKAppSettingsViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .gray
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
  }
}
```

how do i call the Custom IASKSpecifierValuesViewController class?
Note: i'm using storyboard. I'm open in without storyboard solutions. Thank you guys...

Comment: Can you please be more clear about it? What is IASKSpecifierValuesViewController doing? and where do u open it?

Comment: IASKSpecifierValuesViewController is IASKAppsettingsViewController’s detail view. But don’t customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, i found a solution.

i'm override to didSlectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: IASKAppSettingsViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = .black

  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //Creating specifier object
    let specifier = self.settingsReader.specifier(for: indexPath)
    //Creating a custom IASKSpecifierValuesViewController instance
    let targetViewController = SettingsDetail(style: .grouped)
    targetViewController.currentSpecifier = specifier
    targetViewController.settingsStore = settingsStore
    targetViewController.settingsReader = settingsReader
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(targetViewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Detail view source code:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsDetail: IASKSpecifierValuesViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = .black
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good solution right now, to be honest. What you could do: use method swizzling to override the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Another approach would be to use a [custom view](https://github.com/futuretap/inappsettingskit#iaskcustomviewspecifier) where you push your `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController` subclass when selected.

Or you could modify IASK to add a callback in `IASKSettingsDelegate`. This could be something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView valueCellForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier index:(NSUInteger)index;
```

To implement this, the delegate would have to be propagated to `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController` which would do the callback if implemented.

Alternatively, as a more flexible solution we could allow using a custom subclass of `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController`, potentially by specifying `IASKViewControllerClass` in the settings.plist to override the default `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController`.

I'd welcome such a pull request! (I'm the IASK maintainer.)